Some Properties of Injectivity and Surjectivity of Composition of Functions
We know that for sets $X,Y$ and $Z$, if $f : X \rightarrow Y$ and $g : Y \rightarrow Z$, then the composition functions $gof : X \rightarrow Z$ and $fog : Z \rightarrow X$ are defined by $gof(x)=g(f(x)),\forall x \in X$ and $fog(z)=f(g(z)),\forall z \in Z$.
Some properties of injectivity and surjectivity of compositions I got from the page 61 & 62 of the book are-
[1] if both $f$ and $g$ are injective, then $gof$ is also injective.
[2] if both $f$ and $g$ are surjective, then $gof$ is also surjective.
[3] if $gof$ is injective, $f$ is injective but $g$ is not necessarily injective.
[4] if $gof$ is surjective, $g$ is surjective but $f$ is not necessarily surjective.
Proof of [1] :
Let us assume that $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y \rightarrow Z$ are injective i.e. one-one.
$\therefore \forall x_1,x_2 \in X, x_1 \neq x_2 \implies f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$
Now, $f(x_1),f(x_2) \in Y$ and $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$
Again, as $g$ is one-one, $g(f(x_1)) \neq g(f(x_2))$ i.e. $gof(x_1) \neq gof(x_2)$
$\therefore \forall x_1,x_2 \in X, x_1 \neq x_2 \implies gof(x_1) \neq gof(x_2)$
Hence, $gof$ is one-one given that $f$ and $g$ are one-one.
Proof of [2] :
Let us assume that $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y \rightarrow Z$ are surjective i.e. onto.
$\because g$ is onto, $\forall z \in Z, \exists y \in Y$ such that $g(y)=z$
Again, as $f$ is onto and $y \in Y, \exists x \in X$ such that $f(x)=y$
$\therefore \forall z \in Z, \exists x \in X$ such that $g(f(x))=z$  i.e.  $gof(x)=z$
Hence, $gof$ is onto given that $f$ and $g$ are onto.
Proof of [3] :
Let us assume $f : X \rightarrow Y$ and $g : Y \rightarrow Z$ and $gof : X \rightarrow Z$ is injective i.e. one-one.
$\therefore \forall x_1,x_2 \in X, gof(x_1)=gof(x_2) \implies x_1=x_2$ ____ [A]
Suppose $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$
$\therefore g(f(x_1))=gof((x_2))$ i.e. $gof(x_1)=gof(x_2)$.
Using [A], $x_1=x_2$.
$\therefore \forall x_1,x_2 \in X, f(x_1)=f(x_2) \implies x_1=x_2$
$\therefore f$ is injective.
To show that $g$ is not necesssarily one-one, a counter example can be used.
let, $X=${$x_1,x_2$}, $Y=${$y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4$} and $Z=${$z_1,z_2$}
$f:X \rightarrow Y$ is defined by $f(x_1)=y_1$ and $f(x_2)=y_2$
$g:Y \rightarrow Z$ is defined by $g(y_1)=g(y_3)=z_1$ and $g(y_2)=g(y_4)=z_2$
Hence $gof:X \rightarrow Z$ can be defined by $gof(x_1)=g(f(x_1))=g(y_1)=z_1$ and $gof(x_2)=g(f(x_2))=g(y_2)=z_2$
By definition of one-one functions, $gof$ is one-one and $f$ is one-one but $g$ is not one-one.
Hence, we can conclude that if $gof$ is one-one then $f$ is one-one but $g$ is not necessarily one-one.
Proof of [4] :
Let us assume $f : X \rightarrow Y$ and $g : Y \rightarrow Z$ and $gof : X \rightarrow Z$ is surjective i.e. onto.
$\therefore \forall z \in Z, \exists x \in X$ such that $gof(x)=z \implies g(f(x))=z$
But, $\forall x \in X, \exists y \in Y$ such that $y=f(x)$ as $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a function.
Hence, $\forall z \in Z, \exists y \in Y$ such that $g(y)=z$
$\therefore g$ is onto.
Now, $gof$ is onto but $f$ is not necessarily onto can be proved by the same counter example given in proof of [3] where it can be noticed that $gof$ is onto and $g$ is onto but $f$ is not onto.
Hence, it can be concluded that $gof$ is onto implies that $g$ is onto but $f$ is not necessarily onto.
However, our professor has made two propositions.
[5] if $gof$ is one-one and $f$ is onto, then $g$ is one-one.
[6] if gof is onto and $g$ is one-one, then $f$ is onto.
I could neither be able to figure out a proof for these properties nor provide a counter example to disprove it. Can anyone help?

(5) We want to show that $g$ is one-one. Suppose $g(x)=g(y)$. To proceed, we cannot use that $g\circ f$ is one-one directly from $g(x)=g(y)$. But since $f$ is onto, we can find $x^\prime$ and $y^\prime$ such that $f(x^\prime)=x$ and $f(y^\prime)=y$. Then, $g\circ f(x^\prime)=g\circ f(y^\prime)$ so $x^\prime=y^\prime$. Thus, $x=y$.
(6) Take $y$. We want to find $x$ such that $f(x)=y$. Note that this $x$ must satisfy $g\circ f(x)=g(y)$. Hence, since $g\circ f$ is onto, find $x$ such that $g\circ f(x)=g(y)$. By injectivity of $g$, we get $f(x)=y$.
Hope this helps. :)

Thanks. I have figured out another solution of [5] using your solution.

Let's do it by parts.
(a) Suppose that $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ are injective. Then one concludes that:
\begin{align*}
(g\circ f)(x) = (g\circ f)(y) & \Rightarrow g(f(x)) = g(f(y)) \tag{Def. of Composition}\\\\
& \Rightarrow f(x) = f(y) \tag{Injectivity of $g$}\\\\
& \Rightarrow x = y \tag{Injectivity of $f$}
\end{align*}
Consequently, $g\circ f$ is injective.
(b) Suppose that $f:X\to Y$ is surjective and $g:Y\to Z$ is surjective too. Therefore we conclude that:
\begin{align*}
(g\circ f)(X) = g(f(X)) = g(Y) = Z
\end{align*}
Hence the desired claim holds true.
(c) Suppose that $(g\circ f):X\to Z$ is injective. Hence it results that:
\begin{align*}
f(x) = f(y) & \Rightarrow g(f(x)) = g(f(y)) \tag{Substitution Axiom}\\\\
& \Rightarrow (g\circ f)(x) = (g\circ f)(y) \tag{Def. of Composition}\\\\
& \Rightarrow x = y \tag{Injectivity of $g\circ f$}
\end{align*}
Thus $f$ is injective, and we are done.
On the other hand, $g$ might not be injective.
Indeed, suppose that $X: = \{1\}$, $Y := \{1,2\}$ and $Z: = \{2\}$. If we define $f:X\to Y$ as $f(1) := 1$ and we define $g(1) := g(2) := 2$, then $(g\circ f):X\to Y$ is injective, but $g$ is not, and we are done.
(d) Finally, suppose that $(g\circ f):X\to Z$ is surjective. We may conclude that:
\begin{align*}
Z = (g\circ f)(X) = g(f(X)) \subseteq g(Y)
\end{align*}
Given that the relation $g(Y)\subseteq Z$ always holds, it may be deduced that $g(Y) = Z$, and we are done.
However, $f$ need not be surjective. In fact, it suffices to consider the same example as in (c).
Hopefully this helps!
EDIT
(e) Suppose that $(g\circ f):X\to Z$ is one-to-one. Based on the previous results, we conclude $f$ is injective. Since it has also been assumed that $f$ is surjective, then $f$ is bijective. This means that, for every $y_{1}\in Y$ and $y_{2}\in Y$, there corresponds (an unique) $x_{1}\in X$ and (an unique) $x_{2}\in X$ such that $y_{1} = f(x_{1})$ and $y_{2} = f(x_{2})$. If we deny the definition of being injective, one gets:
\begin{align*}
(\exists y_{1}\in Y)(\exists y_{2}\in Y)((g(y_{1}) = g(y_{2}))\wedge(y_{1}\neq y_{2}))
\end{align*}
which results into claiming that
\begin{align*}
(\exists x_{1}\in X)(\exists x_{2}\in X)((g(f(x_{1})) = g(f(x_{2})))\wedge(x_{1}\neq x_{2}))
\end{align*}
that is an absurd because it has been assumed that $g\circ f$ is injective, and we are done.
(f) Similar approach applies to the last case.
Can you take it from here?

The OP couldn't do (5) and (6), they have already done (1)-(4).

@ultralegend5385 Thanks for pointing it out. I've overlooked the question.

@ultralegend5385 I have provided an answer to the proposed exercise now.

Any reason for the downvote?

@ÁtilaCorreia I had downvoted it for the obvious reason that you had not read the question properly. After the edit I upvoted it

Thank you guys. I've figured out the proofs using your help. However, I have modified the proofs a little bit such that I can easily understand. So I'd like to share them.
Proof of [5] :
Let us assume that $y_1,y_2 \in Y$ such that $y_1 \neq y_2$
$\because f:X \rightarrow Y$ is onto, $\exists x_1,x_2 \in X$ such that $f(x_1)=y_1$ and $f(x_2)=y_2$
Clearly, $x_1 \neq x_2$ as otherwise $f:X \rightarrow Y$ can not be defined as a function.
Now, as $gof$ is one-one, $x_1 \neq x_2 \implies gof(x_1) \neq gof(x_2)$  i.e.  $g(f(x_1)) \neq g(f(x_2))$ or $g(y_1) \neq g(y_2)$
$\therefore \forall y_1,y_2 \in Y, y_1 \neq y_2 \implies g(y_1) \neq g(y_2)$
Hence, $g$ is one-one given that $gof$ is one-one and $f$ is onto.
Proof of [6] :
Let us assume that $y \in Y$
$\because g: Y \rightarrow Z$ is a function, $ \exists z \in Z$ such that $g(y)=z$
Now, as $gof$ is onto and $z \in Z, \exists x \in X$ such that $gof(x)=z$ i.e. $g(f(x))=z$
$\therefore g(f(x))=g(y)$
$\because g$ is one-one, $g(f(x))=g(y) \implies f(x)=y$
$\therefore \forall y \in Y, \exists x \in X$ such that $f(x)=y$
Hence, $f$ is onto given that $gof$ is onto and $g$ is one-one.
